# Change style of textbox parent when focusing on textbox

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="password">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to change the styling of the parent `li` through CSS whenever you focus on the child textbox. Is there a way to do this with the `:focus` selector, or some other selector? Or do I need to do this with Javascript?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Comment: How about applying a thick border to each input? Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dgXcE/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use css select the parent when their child on focus.
But I only know in the javascript way you can do this.

for jQuery

```
$('input').on('focus', function(){  
    $(this).parent().css(/* the css you want to change */)
})
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "input" ).focus(function() {
$( this ).parent().css( "list-style", "none" );
});
```

see  http://jsfiddle.net/SGETp/6/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to focus on Li, its better you use image or change the border colors, this is depend on your idea that how you are gonna use it.

Try to use this in your css file :

```
ul {list-style-type:none;}
input {border:10px solid yellow;}
input:focus {border:10px solid green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my initial comment: css doesn't have parent selectors.

If your objective is to highlight the input that has focus, a workaround would be to give each input a thick border:

```
ul {list-style-type:none;}
input {border:20px solid green;}
input:focus {border:20px solid red;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dgXcE